# no scrollbar, but i want one

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I really would like to get a scrollbar for the page cause atm the stuff goes out of the window as if overflow: hidden is set but i didn't use that.

I could drop all my code here but i think a jsfiddle will serve better:

http://jsfiddle.net/K4RFU/

I tried

```
body {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and also with scroll, auto, inherit, it all didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you set a *fixed* position to everything.

Removing the fixed position from the `entries` element cause scroll bar to appear. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4RFU/1/).